# Xlsx Writer Critera If Blank

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Given this format:

```
format0 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'none'})
```

I'd like to apply it (no background color) if the cell is blank.
Here's what I've tried so far:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B14', 
{'type':'cell', 
'criteria': '=isblank()=True', 
'format': format0
})
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'value'
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not using a correct entry for 'criteria', but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The border of the blank cells are not visible if you use white background color as given in the answer above.It can be modified to 
`format0 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'white','border':1,'border_color':'#D5DBDB'})`to give a border to the blank cells that looks similar to default excel cells.

Answer (score 5):

One solution:

It appears that setting the color to 'none' produces blue cells, for some reason. So instead, I opted to color blank cells white:

```
format0 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'white'})
```

Then, by reading the documentation (what a great idea!):

```
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B14', {'type':'blanks', 'format': format0})
```

I put this **before** other conditional formats for the same column.

Comment: Thanks dude, this was useful! Was searching for 'empty' instead of 'blanks'.


For reference, here is the page in the docs:

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html

Comment: How to give a range such that the whole sheet looks like `white` colored?

Comment: @JayPatel, You can specify some big number in this worksheet.conditional_format('A1:ZZ100', {'type':'blanks', 'format': format0})